# Import causing syntax error in scss using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sass, web-essentials

I imported into my Visual Studio 2013 a template that I purchased using scss. I then installed the latest Web Essentials to use this feature but I am struggling with it.

Here is a sample of my structure

```
main.scss /* imports several child scss  */
@import 'helpers/sub1';   
@import 'helpers/sub2';   
@import 'helpers/sub3';
```

My issues comes when in a child scss it refers to another scss. See print screen below the

[image: This my scss with the import causing the error]
[image: This is without the import]

Answer (score 0):

I found problems such as this all the time, when using Web Essentials to compile SASS.  In my opinion the SASS compiling has always been a bit flaky in Web Essentials.  In fact they have taken the decision to remove compilation from Web Essentials 2015 (see *2015.0.2* in [changelog](http://vswebessentials.com/changelog))

In the end I ditched Web Essentials in favour of compiling with Grunt and using Task Runner Explorer in Visual Studio to manage the running of my Grunt task.  I found this a much better way of compiling.

If you want to look in detail at how to implement this with Grunt and Task Runner Explorer, I wrote a [post](http://www.iambacon.co.uk/blog/getting-started-with-grunt-sass-and-task-runner-explorer-visual-studio) about it

Comment: Thanks Colin, I'll have a look at your implementation.